# custom cursor using querySelector lags in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/rfpRZ2t_BrQ) to have a shape that follows my cursor, this works great and runs smoothly in Chrome and Firefox but for some reason, in Safari it lags a lot.

Here is an Imgur preview of what the two browsers look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZieH.jpg

My javascript code

```
<script>
            const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+(e.pageY - 10)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX - 10)+"px;")
        })

        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cursor.classList.add("expand");

            setTimeout(() => {
                cursor.classList.remove("expand");
            }, 500)
        })
</script>
```

My CSS

```
    .cursor {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #00AEC8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: cursorAnim .5s infinite alternate;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I am also willing to disable the cursor animation within Safari if that's possible and easier.

Comment: Try altering the `style` property instead of setting the attribute.  `cursor.style.top = (e.pageY - 10)+"px"; cursor.style.left = (e.pageX - 10)+"px"`

Comment: the lag is still present in safari unfortunately